# Xen domU fails to start with kernel panic

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

My dom0 is Gentoo 3.3.2, the kernel is compiled with Xen support. I am planing to use the same kernel to boot my domU.

This is my domU configuration file:

```
  1 vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]
  2 vcpus = 1
  3 uuid = "c1d751ba-e228-45e6-b7a8-01895e88a815"
  4 root = "/dev/xvda ro"
  5 name = "Gentoo"
  6 memory = 512
  7 kernel = "/boot/kernel-3.3.2-gentoo"
  8 extra = "4 console=hvc0"
  9 disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vg/gentoo,xvda,w' ]
```

`/dev/vg/gentoo` is an LV. After I ran `xl create -c gentoo.cfg`, the guest started and stopped with the following error *(only the last few lines)*:

```
[    0.122019] netconsole: network logging started
[    0.122180] Root-NFS: no NFS server address
[    0.122186] VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
[    0.122280] VFS: Cannot open root device "xvda" or unknown-block(2,0)
[    0.123056] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    0.123056] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Xen, but when you say you've compiled your kernel with xen support do you have the `xenblk` driver/module? I think it's something like `CONFIG_XEN_BLKDEV_FRONTEND` in your `.config`. Have you tried any other xen configurations just to see if they work? For example, using the `tap:aio` interface?

Comment: I do have compiled the `xenblk` module. But I forgot to load them ;P